# Seaborn plots dots instead of bars in barchart

Tags: python, seaborn

My goal is plot a bar chart of job execution times using [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) library. Data are read from CVS file. However, for some reason data are plotted as dots instead of bars.

[image: output plot]

Why is it so?

Here's the code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="whitegrid")

history = pd.read_csv('history.csv', usecols = ['host', 'pipeline_group', 'pipeline', 'job', 'cruise_job_duration'])
history['absolute_job_name'] =  history['pipeline'].map(str) + "/" +  history['job']

history = history.groupby(by='absolute_job_name', as_index=False)['cruise_job_duration']\
    .sum()\
    .sort_values(by='cruise_job_duration', ascending=False)\
    .head(10)

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
sns.set_color_codes("pastel")
plot = sns.catplot(x="cruise_job_duration", y="absolute_job_name", data=history, label="Total", color="b")
plot.savefig("output.png")
```

Comment: Should you have `sns.barplot` instead of `sns.catplot`?  Have a look here https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/horizontal_barplot.html

Comment: Maybe you forgot to tell seaborn that you actually want a bar plot, `kind="bar"`?

Comment: It looks like you need to pass `catplot` the keyword `kind="bar"` or it defaults to a scatter

Comment: @G.Anderson Right! It helped. Thank you!